# Static IP with wireless bridge

Tags: networking, static-ip, wireless-bridge

I have a pretty simple network with the main router being a Netgear R8500.  I am using an ASUS RT-N66U router in repeater mode to connect device on another floor via wireless bridge including a network printer and a file server.

I need a static IP address for the printer and file server, but every time I assign one, it changes when the IP addresses refresh (usually a day or two).  This is because all of my devices that come through the wireless bridge show the MAC address of the wireless bridge, so the main router that assigns IP addresses doesn't know which one is the correct device.

Is there a way to fix this?  Every time I set up a printer on one of the computers, it works for about two days, and then I have to go in and change the IP address.

Thanks!

Comment: Set up DHCP reservations in your router's DHCP server.

Comment: The problem is that my bridge, printer, and file server (and all wireless connections) have the same MAC address, so the DHCP server juggles the static IPs between those devices.  So I will set my printer to the static IP and the next day, the router will have that IP.

Comment: Really? How on earth did that happen?

Answer (score 0):

Set the static IP addresses directly on the printer and file server - instead of the DHCP server (router).